# Keybindings for major modes

Tags: key-bindings

I have the following function that sets keymaps for `outline-minor-mode`.
I wonder how I may avoid repeating all this for different major-modes.  Perhaps
have a list of modes that I could loop through, but do not know what a
good would look like.

```
(defun tika-elisp-view ()
  "Viewing emacs lisp outline structures."

  (define-key emacs-lisp-mode-map
     (kbd "H-o s") #'outline-show-subtree)

  (define-key emacs-lisp-mode-map
     (kbd "H-o i") #'outline-show-children)

  (define-key emacs-lisp-mode-map
     (kbd "H-o k") #'outline-show-branches)

  (define-key emacs-lisp-mode-map
     (kbd "H-o e") #'outline-show-entry) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to provide a list of major modes to some function and have that function define the keys as you show in the keymaps of those modes.

```lisp
(defun set-my-outline-mode-keys (modes)
  "Set my keys in MODES."
  (dolist (mode  modes)
    (let ((map  (symbol-value (intern (format "%s-map" mode)))))
      (define-key map (kbd "H-o s") #'outline-show-subtree)     
      (define-key map (kbd "H-o i") #'outline-show-children)     
      (define-key map (kbd "H-o k") #'outline-show-branches)    
      (define-key map (kbd "H-o e") #'outline-show-entry))))

(set-my-outline-mode-keys '(emacs-lisp-mode text-mode))
```

(In the upcoming Emacs 29 release you can use `keymap-set` instead of `define-key`.  I don't see a great advantage, but you might prefer it.)

Comment: Yes, providing a list of major modes would get me a much cleaner and compact implementation.  Then simply join a `-map` followed by an `intern`.  Works good.

Comment: What type of advantages would `keymap-set` offer in this situation ?

Comment: No idea. I'm not following that change. Well, it lets you use the same key descriptions as input, directly, without needing to use `kbd`. Dunno what else is touted.

Comment: Not much difference then, just a different calling sequence.

Comment: Check `NEWS` (`C-h n`) in an Emacs build that has this.